# Add bridged adapter in qemu

Tags: networking, qemu, kvm, libvirt, hypervisor

I am running VM (ubuntu 14) on a locally built version of QEMU. I am trying to attach predefined network bridge(s) to the VM, so that VM can talk to outside world. What commands do i use?
I referred to qemu wiki @ http://wiki.qemu.org/Features-Done/HelperNetworking

Running following command throws error:

> > ./qemu-system-i386 ../../../img/ubuntu_server_console_bak.qcow2 -monitor stdio -m 1024 -net nic,model=rtl8139 bridge,br=ha207

qemu-system-i386: -net nic,model=rtl8139: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists

I have used kvm before to launch my VM. I was able to attach my network bridge with following changes in config.xml.

```
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:00:00:00:00:ce'/>
      <source bridge='ha207' name='eth0'/>
      <virtualport type='openvswitch'>
      </virtualport>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='control_sw' name='eth1'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <virtualport type='openvswitch'>
      </virtualport>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='virbr0' name='eth2'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

How do i achieve same in qemu?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple typo.

Qemu interprets **bridge,br=ha207** as a filename for the disk image but it already has one. You will see it if you drop the **../../../img/ubuntu_server_console_bak.qcow2** option.

Simply add **-net bridge,br=ha207** instead of **bridge,br=ha207**.